# Golang Mutex to Lock Specific Variable/Map

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

I'm a little confused on how mutex's work in Golang, even though I've used them before.

**Here are my questions:**

1. What exactly does a mutex lock? (How) Do you use it to lock a specific variable only?
2. Should I use channels instead of a mutex?
3. Is there a difference between a mutex and a locker?

I'm developing a highly concurrent website with golang, and I need to manage each person's wallet at different times and I am trying to avoid any races in my program. For example, if my program wants to add 500 credits to a user, it will read the current balance for the user (from firebase) and add 500 then update the value. But if it does this twice for some reason, there may be an incorrect change to the user's wallet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is a Mutex?**

In general, a "mutual exclusion" construct (or mutex) helps with concurrency control.  Languages that define mutexes let programmers define a critical section of code that can only be entered by a single thread of execution.  [Here is a simple example of using mutexes in Go](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes).  [Here is a bit more detailed example of using mutexes](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-synchronizing-state-with-mutexes-golang).

**Mutex or Channel?**

When deciding whether to use a mutex or channel based design in your Go app, the choices aren't always terribly clear.  This [wiki article from the Go github repo](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MutexOrChannel)  has the following advice:

*Channel*: passing ownership of data,
distributing units of work,
communicating async results

*Mutex*: caches, state

**Mutex or sync.Locker?**

As @JimB pointed out, the [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) type in Go satisfies the [`sync.Locker`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Locker) interface type.  Notice how `sync.Mutex` has `Lock()` and `Unlock()` methods?  So to Go, a `sync.Mutex` is a `sync.Locker`.

For more [help with Go interfaces, check out this great blog post](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go).

Comment: -1 Sorry Dan,  the OP asks what exactly is locked and this is not answered. There are links to more details but links rot and SO answers should include all relevant detail in the text of the answer.

Comment: *asks what exactly is locked* .... Hmmm, I guess I thought I answered that with "mutexes let programmers define a critical section of code that can only be entered by a single thread of execution"

Comment: I think the confusion comes because in other languages a `lock` statement would apply to an object reference. More confusion exists because a Mutex in Win32 is system wide, its one way for an app to know another is running, so "what gets locked" is just an identifier, e.g. your app name.

Answer (score 2):

1. A `Mutex` only locks itself. It's up to you to decide what that lock signifies in your code.
2. Use channels for synchronizing and communicating between goroutines. Use a mutex to provide "mutual exclusion" around a single logical resource.
3. A mutex satisfies the `sync.Locker` interface. Something that requires a `sync.Locker` could use a `sync.Mutex` or a `sync.RWMutex` interchangeably.

Synchronization primitives aren't related to the concept of preventing duplicate transactions. Correct use of synchronization will only prevent data races in your program.

Comment: I read on the godoc that a mutex satisfies the sync.Locker interface, but didn't really understand what it meant. I was looking for an explination. Also, how would I use a mutex to lock only a specific variable? (It's up to you to decide what that signifies?)

Comment: @Acidic: ["Interfaces"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) are a primary Go concept that you need to understand to use the language. Maybe start with the official documentation, like the corresponding sections in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces), or the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9). There simply is no relation between a mutex and what it locks other than how you use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If the state is not in memory. You really don't need synchronous locks. But let's say all of the users wallets are inside of one Map. You would need one because concurrent writes will cause a race condition.